# javascript recalculate deeply nested array elemnts numbers

Tags: javascript

I got the following array:

```
let data =  [
        {"title": {number: 1},
            "children": [
                {"title": {number: 1.1}},
                {"title": {number: 1.2}},
                {"title": {number: 1.3}},
                {"title": {number: 1.4}},
                {"title": {number: 1.5}}
            ]
        },
        {"title": {number: 2},
            "children": [
                {"title":{number: 2.1}},
                {"title":{number: 2.2},
                    "children": [
                        {"title":{number: 2.2.1}},
                        {"title":{number: 2.2.2}},
                        {"title":{number: 2.2.3}},
                        {"title":{number: 2.2.4}} 
                    ]
                },
                {"title":{number: 2.3}},
                {"title":{number: 2.4}}
            ]
        },
        {"title": {number: 3},
            "children": []
        }
    ];
```

Every element of this array may change its place, new element may be added, existing element may be removed. The task is to recalculate elements numbers in order to maintain their correct order. For example, if element with number `2.2.2` is removed, the other elements become `2.2.1`, `2.2.2` and `2.2.3`. If some element is removed with its children, numbers for all other elements shoud also be recalculated. Any ideas how to do that would be welcome. Thank you

Comment: Why have numbers at all.They are easily calculated from the hierarchy

Comment: Any ideas how to find them out from hierarchy? As far as I understand I need to recursively keep track of nesting level and add increment for relevant element...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39887381/how-to-get-nested-array-length-in-javascript have you checked this ?

Comment: Yes, you need to recurse. but as you see `data[0].title` is the first title, `data[1]title` the second. `data[1].children[0]` is 2.1 etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create recursive function that you will call every time your object structure changes to recalculate the positions of each element in the tree.

```js
function recalc(data, prev = '') {
  data.forEach((e, i) => {
    let dot = prev ? '.' : '';
    let number = prev + dot + (i + 1);

    if (e.children) {
      recalc(e.children, number)
    }

    if (e.title) {
      e.title.number = number
    }
  })
}

const data1 = [{"title":{"number":1},"children":[{"title":{"number":1.1}},{"title":{"number":1.2}},{"title":{"number":1.3}},{"title":{"number":1.4}},{"title":{"number":1.5}}]},{"title":{"number":2},"children":[{"title":{"number":2.1}},{"title":{"number":2.2},"children":[{"title":{"number":"2.2.1"}},{"title":{"number":"2.2.2"}},{"title":{"number":"2.2.3"}},{"title":{"number":"2.2.4"}}]},{"title":{"number":2.3}},{"title":{"number":2.4}}]},{"title":{"number":3},"children":[]}]
recalc(data1);
console.log(data1)

const data2 = [{"title":{"number":1},"children":[{"title":{"number":1.1}},{"title":{"number":1.2}},{"title":{"number":1.5}}]},{"title":{"number":2},"children":[{"title":{"number":2.1}},{"title":{"number":2.2},"children":[{"title":{"number":"2.2.3"}},{"title":{"number":"2.2.4"}}]},{"title":{"number":2.3}},{"title":{"number":2.4}}]},{"title":{"number":3},"children":[{title: {}, children: [{title: {}}, {title: {}}]}]}]
recalc(data2);
console.log(data2)
```